# angularjs modal change template?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a list page, when click a row, will popup a modal view page to show its content, then in it click edit button, I want the popup view page can direct to edit page, that is from one modal view page redirect to another modal edit page, I use angularjs modal to show view page, so how can I change modal content to edit page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Girafa, I use a simple way(although code is some verbose). I create two Controller and when open view modal, pass $scope in the Options, then when click edit button, first call cancel current modal, then open edit view. like this:
$modalInstance.close('cancel');
$scope.openedit(id);

Comment: What is the 'cancel' parameter for?

Answer (score 0):

You may fetch your template using $templateCache.get() or making http request.
Then compile it using $compile(template). After template compiling you can put your template anywhere you want in the DOM by using jQuery/jqLite — all angular bindings will work.

Comment: thank you, but I am a beginner for angularjs, $compile and templateCache is too advanced for me